# Magento 2 - 'Choose an option...' text

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento2

I have found similar questions to this for Magento 1. However haven't come across the question for Magento 2.

I'm looking to change the default text for configurable products with select boxes.
By default, the drop-down box for configurable products displays 'Choose an option...'.
I'd like to change this to 'Select {attribute default label}'.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this in two ways. 1. By translating in csv. 2. By overriding module-configurable-product from vendor folder.

1) Open en_US.csv file from the below path

```
vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\i18n\
```

Find the "Choose an Option..." text in first column. Replace your text in the second column and save it. Clean the cache and check it.

**or**

2) Override the configurable.phtml from below link

```
vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\view\frontend\templates\product\view\type\options\
```

Change the below in this file. Find the code:

```
<option value=""><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
```

Change from:

```
<option value=""><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
```

To:

```
<option value=""><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Select ').strtolower($block->escapeHtml($_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getStoreLabel())) ?></option>
```